# How to restart deployed app when one node in cluster goes down?

Tags: wildfly-11, mod-cluster

I have to restart a deployed app when one node in the cluster(2 nodes Active/Passive) goes down, how do I handle a node failure and then restart the app?

I'm using mod_cluster for hot_standby and load balancing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I cleaned up some typos in your post to make it easier to read. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restart the application server from the balancer if that is what you are trying to do?

If your App has crashed or become undeployed you could have a crontask that runs on the server and checks the  status of the App

If  you are hosting in a cloud environment (eg. AWS) you could use the EC2 API's to reboot any instances that have become unresponsive from the balancer